# Swift: delegate method won't fire

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, protocols, delegation

I am trying to trigger a method in another view controller depending on whether or not the user's device is online.

The method is called from *ConnectionService.swift* which is set up as follows:

```
protocol ConnectionServiceDelegate: class {
func didChangeStatus()
}

weak var delegate: ConnectionServiceDelegate?

    func updateConnectionStatus(_ status: Connectivity.Status) {
    switch status {
    case .connected, .connectedViaWiFi, .connectedViaCellular:
        updateLabelWith(connectionStatus: .connected)

    case .notConnected, .connectedViaWiFiWithoutInternet, .connectedViaCellularWithoutInternet:
        updateLabelWith(connectionStatus: .disconnected)
    }

    delegate?.didChangeStatus()
    }
```

The VC in which I am trying to trigger the method is set up with this in viewDidLoad():

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    stackView.customPadding(BaseFlightLookupViewController.submitButtonVerticalPadding, after: date)


     connectionService = ConnectionService()
     connectionService?.delegate = self
}
```

and then this in an extension:

```
extension RetrieveCompletedOrderViewController: ConnectionServiceDelegate {
func didChangeStatus() {
    print("Delegate triggered")
}
```

}

Now I know the delegating class is hitting the correct line but why is my method in this RetrieveCompletedOrderViewController not being triggered?

EDITED:

updateConnectionStatus called as follows:

```
    private func prepareConnectivityListener() {
    let connectivityChanged: (Connectivity) -> Void = { [weak self] connectivity in
        self?.updateConnectionStatus(connectivity.status)
    }

    connectivity.whenConnected = connectivityChanged
    connectivity.whenDisconnected = connectivityChanged
    connectivity.startNotifier(queue: queue)
}
```

and this method called here:

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.prepareUI()
    }
    prepareConnectivityListener()
    return true
}
```

Comment: where you call `updateConnectionStatus` ?

Comment: just added to original post

Comment: `connectionService?.delegate = self` is in `RetrieveCompletedOrderViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: yes it is indeed

Comment: Did you make sure connectionService initialize in viewDidLoad is not nil?
because I see it is nullable.